# How to load toplevel modules silently

Tags: ocaml, toplevel, ocaml-toplevel

In my `~/.ocamlinit`, I have some directives:

```
#use "topfind"
#thread
#require "core.top"
```

As a result, every time the OCaml toplevel (i.e. `ocaml`) starts, I get this huge wall of text:

```
        OCaml version 4.02.3

Findlib has been successfully loaded. Additional directives:
  #require "package";;      to load a package
  #list;;                   to list the available packages
  #camlp4o;;                to load camlp4 (standard syntax)
  #camlp4r;;                to load camlp4 (revised syntax)
  #predicates "p,q,...";;   to set these predicates
  Topfind.reset();;         to force that packages will be reloaded
  #thread;;                 to enable threads

/usr/lib/ocaml/threads: added to search path
/usr/lib/ocaml/unix.cma: loaded
/usr/lib/ocaml/threads/threads.cma: loaded
/usr/lib/ocaml/compiler-libs: added to search path
/usr/lib/ocaml/bigarray.cma: loaded
/home/user/.opam/system/lib/bin_prot: added to search path
/home/user/.opam/system/lib/bin_prot/bin_prot.cma: loaded
/home/user/.opam/system/lib/fieldslib: added to search path
/home/user/.opam/system/lib/fieldslib/fieldslib.cma: loaded
/usr/lib/ocaml/nums.cma: loaded
/home/user/.opam/system/lib/num-top: added to search path
/home/user/.opam/system/lib/num-top/num_top.cma: loaded
/home/user/.opam/system/lib/num: added to search path
/home/user/.opam/system/lib/sexplib: added to search path
/home/user/.opam/system/lib/sexplib/sexplib.cma: loaded
/home/user/.opam/system/lib/ppx_assert: added to search path
/home/user/.opam/system/lib/ppx_assert/ppx_assert_lib.cma: loaded
/home/user/.opam/system/lib/ppx_bench: added to search path
/home/user/.opam/system/lib/ppx_bench/ppx_bench_lib.cma: loaded
/home/user/.opam/system/lib/ppx_expect: added to search path
/home/user/.opam/system/lib/ppx_expect/expect_test_common.cma: loaded
/home/user/.opam/system/lib/ppx_expect/expect_test_config.cma: loaded
/home/user/.opam/system/lib/ppx_inline_test: added to search path
/home/user/.opam/system/lib/ppx_inline_test/inline_test_config.cma: loaded
/home/user/.opam/system/lib/ppx_inline_test/ppx_inline_test_lib.cma: loaded
/home/user/.opam/system/lib/ppx_expect/expect_test_collector.cma: loaded
/home/user/.opam/system/lib/result: added to search path
/home/user/.opam/system/lib/result/result.cma: loaded
/home/user/.opam/system/lib/typerep: added to search path
/home/user/.opam/system/lib/typerep/typerep_lib.cma: loaded
/home/user/.opam/system/lib/variantslib: added to search path
/home/user/.opam/system/lib/variantslib/variantslib.cma: loaded
/home/user/.opam/system/lib/core_kernel: added to search path
/home/user/.opam/system/lib/core_kernel/core_kernel.cma: loaded
/home/user/.opam/system/lib/sexplib/sexplib_unix.cma: loaded
/home/user/.opam/system/lib/core: added to search path
/home/user/.opam/system/lib/core/core.cma: loaded
/home/user/.opam/system/lib/core/core_top.cma: loaded
#
```

Is there a way to silence the loading of modules when the toplevel starts?

Comment: I don't know such option, but I can recommend to use **utop**, which is really nice top-level environment and it doesn't display such wall of text after start: https://opam.ocaml.org/blog/about-utop/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[trivelt's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49642515/how-to-load-toplevel-modules-silently#comment86297070_49642515) has the best answer - use utop! - but if you or others want to use `ocaml` directly you can set `Sys.interactive` to `false` to silence most of the status messages.  For example:

Noisy:

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.06.0

# #use "topfind";;
- : unit = ()
Findlib has been successfully loaded. Additional directives:
  #require "package";;      to load a package
  #list;;                   to list the available packages
  #camlp4o;;                to load camlp4 (standard syntax)
  #camlp4r;;                to load camlp4 (revised syntax)
  #predicates "p,q,...";;   to set these predicates
  Topfind.reset();;         to force that packages will be reloaded
  #thread;;                 to enable threads

- : unit = ()
```

Quieter:

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.06.0

# Sys.interactive := false;;
- : unit = ()
# #use "topfind";;
- : unit = ()
- : unit = ()
```

You can put `Sys.interactive := false;;` at the start of your `.ocamlinit` file and `Sys.interactive := true;;` at the end if you want to have this work automatically.